# Swift NSTableview convert obj-c to swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

Hey the original apple guide in obj-c is here,

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW6

example 3.2

I have been following through the guide and can not get the program to work, i am getting these errors:

```
'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'identifier'
 line: result.identifier = "HelloWorld"
```

and

```
error: cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject?' to type '()'
Line: return result
```

What am i doing wrong?

```
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int){
    var names: [String] = ["Anna","Alex","brain","jack","gg"]
    var result: AnyObject? = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("HelloWorld", owner: self)

    if result == nil
    {
        // Create the new NSTextField with a frame of the {0,0} with the width
        // of the table.
        result = NSTextField(frame: NSRect())
        // set identifier of the NSTextField instance to HelloWorld.
        result.identifier = "HelloWorld"

    }

    result = names[row]
    return result

}
```

New Working code

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSTextField{


    var names = ["Anna","Alex","Brain","Jack","Hello"]
    var result: NSTextField? = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("HelloWorld", owner: self) as? NSTextField        
    if result == nil
    {
        // Create the new NSTextField with a frame of the {0,0} with the width
        // of the table.
        result = NSTextField(frame: NSRect())
        // set identifier of the NSTextField instance to HelloWorld.
        result?.identifier = "HelloWorld"

    }
    result!.bezeled = false
    result?.stringValue = names[row]
    return result!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
var result: AnyObject? = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("HelloWorld", owner: self)
```

you have declared the `result` variable as an optional AnyObject - and this protocol doesn't have an `identifier` property, which is instead a property of `NSTextField`.

What you should do is declare that variable using the correct type:

```
var result: NSTextField? = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("HelloWorld", owner: self) as? NSTextField
```

which can also be shortened thanks to type inference:

```
var result = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("HelloWorld", owner: self) as? NSTextField
```

---

Side note: I think your `if` is checking for the opposite condition:

```
if result != nil
```

whereas I think it should be:

```
if result == nil
```

---

Side note 2

There's no return value declared in your function, but you are returning an instance of `NSTextField`.
You should change the signature to:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSView
```

and change the return statement to:

```
return result!
```

Note that `result` is defined as optional, but looking at the method implementation, at the end a non-nil value is available, so I've used forced unwrapping and declared the method to return a non-optional value. Of course feel free to change that if you want.

Comment: I made those two changes but running into an issue at the return statment  "Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSTextField?' to type '()'"  the identifier does work now though.

Comment: That's because you haven't specified a return type in your method declaration, so it expects an empty tuple (i.e. `Void`), which means no return value